# Using micro_ros_arduino with ESP32 with wireless ROS system

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, ros2, wifi

I am retired and programming has always been a hobby but also my College Degree in Game/Simulations (90%). So I am familiar with a lot of programming as I used it in work for some development/problem solving, but was always passed to more seasoned programmers (since not my job) to implement in the systems.

Now that I am retired I would like to finish several robotic ideas, and I know I will need a messaging system, and after looking at mavlink,ROS and others have decided to go with ROS but my micro board will be the ESP32 or perhaps 2-3 linked. But for now just assuming one.

With ROS, specifically using the ESP for sensor connecting, I am curious if rather than having a Pi onboard running Roscore can it be setup to run over the wireless network? And eliminate one piece of hardware. In my cases the robots will always be in range of local network.

So the ESP32 running on robot, Pi 4 running ROScore on local network both connected Wifi.

If not what are my options?

Would it be better to run the ESP32 and Pi4 on the Robot hardwired? If that is the minimal configuration can a host be added at the router later? At some point I would probably want a groundstation, if anything for remote control and video.

Hope this makes sense. The networking and messaging control is where I get confused. In all of the video tutorials it seems people are using 3 computers for simple projects. I am hoping I can get away with bare minimal and expand later if needed.